# How does typename assignment work in C++ (typename =)?

Tags: c++, enable-if

I came across this example when looking at `std::enable_if`:

```
template<class T,
typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_array<T>::value> >
void destroy(T* t) 
{
   for(std::size_t i = 0; i < std::extent<T>::value; ++i) {
    destroy((*t)[i]);
   }
}
```

In template argument lists, you can put untemplated classes/structs. So the above code is still possible when we remove the `typename =`. What does the `typename =` in this code mean and do?

Comment: default for unnamed type (used for SFINAE here). Default can be seen for regular function too:  `void foo(int = 42)` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `typename` on the 2nd template argument indicates the argument is a type rather than a constant value. The argument has no name specified, but the `=` indicates it has a default type if the caller doesn't specify one. In this case, that type is the result of `enable_if_t<...>` (aka `std::enable_if<...>::type`).

`std::enable_if` has 2 template arguments. The 1st argument takes in a boolean constant, and the 2nd argument specifies the type of the `std::enable_if<...>::type` member. The 2nd argument is `void` by default. The `type` member is defined only when the boolean is true, otherwise it is undefined when the boolean is false. In this case, that boolean is the result of `std::is_array<T>::value`.

So, if `T` is an array type, `std::is_array<T>::value` will be `true`, thus `std::enable_if<true, void>::type` will be `void`, and the final template will be:

```
template<class T, typename _ = void>
void destroy(T* t) 
{
   ...
}
```

Otherwise, if `T` is not an array type, `std::is_array<T>::value` will be `false`, thus `std::enable_if<false, void>::type` will be undefined, and the final template will be:

```
template<class T, typename _ = [undefined] >
void destroy(T* t) 
{
   ...
}
```

And thus the template will be disabled since it is invalid.

Comment: I have expanded my answer, hopefully it makes more sense to you now.

Answer (score 0):

***First***.
**typename** and **class** have the same meaning when used inside a template.

***Second***.
**typename = ...** means a default value has been specified for it which gets used if you do not explicitly specify a second parameter in the template.